# Can jqGrid show the pager only when it exceeds the rowNum

Tags: jqgrid

Is there a way to only show the pager when the rowNum has been reached?
For example, if my grid is set to show 10 rows per page but yet my results only contain 3 rows, can we hide the pager? Conversely, if my results contains 15 rows, then show the pager.
In my current grid, the pager works fine, I just don't want it to show if its not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From GGG's answer I took the approach of hiding the pager on the 'onInitGrid' event and showing the pager on the gridComplete event. This works great.

```
            onInitGrid: function() {
                $("#accountSettingsNav").hide();
            },
            gridComplete: function() {
                var totalRecords = $("#accountSettingsGrid").jqGrid("getGridParam","records");
                var rowNum = $("#accountSettingsGrid").jqGrid("getGridParam","rowNum");
                if (totalRecords > rowNum) {
                    $("#accountSettingsNav").show();
                }
            },
```

The pager still updates when it is hidden, so there were no issues there.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure this is right approach , as I cant find any pre-defined jqgrid methods. But you can use
"onGridCompleteTopics" to check for total number of records returned.

```
 $("#gridId").jqGrid('getGridParam','records');
```

if that exceeds your limit, you can manually hide (Display:none) the pager DIV .